# Использование this в объекте return

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты

Есть код подобного вида:

```
    function test() {
        return {
                foo: 2,
                bar: 3,
                value: this.foo + this.bar
            }
    }
```

Почему `this` не ссылается на нужный объект?

Comment: Если среди ответов есть тот, который решил твою проблему, ставь галочку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вычисление выражения `this.foo + this.bar` происходит в контексте функции `test`. Вы не можете в момент создания нового объекта обращаться к его свойствам.

Добиться похожего результата можно так:

```js
function test() {
    return {
        foo: 2,
        bar: 3,
        get value() {
             return this.foo + this.bar;
        }
    };
}

console.log(test().value);
```

В таком случае значение свойства `value` будет вычисляться динамически.

Answer (score 2):

объект еще не создан, когда вы используете `this` в выражении и поэтому он не определен. Для того чтобы передать контекст объекта, можно использовать функцию [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```js
function test() {
    return {
        foo: 2,
        bar: 3,
       value: function() {
             return this.foo + this.bar;
        }
    };
}

console.log(test().value());
```